# Circuit breaker policy with Polly

Tags: .net, polly, circuit-breaker

I am trying to implement a circuit breaker with Polly. One of the dependent services I have becomes unavailable during a certain time period and becomes available after a short window. This is a multi-tenant service and the unavailability is at different times for different tenants. Is there a way to create a circuit breaker based on context ? Is there a way for me to add some logic to check before breaking the circuit?

Comment: Are your tenants separated by sub-domains as well? For example: `tenant1.yourdownstreamservice.com`, `tenat2.yourdownstreamservice.com`

Comment: No, they are not. The only way to know the tenant is through headers.

Comment: If that information is echod back inside the response headers then you can create a `Handle` which examines the `HttpResponseMessage`'s `Headers` collection: `.Handle<HttpResponseMessage>(resp => resp.Headers.TryGetValues("x-tenantId", ....`. But the thing is whenever the CB opens then all requests are rejected immediately with a `BrokenCircuitException`. So the best way would be to have separated CBs for each tenant.